# Magento 2: How many products sold Query

Tags: magento2, product, database, query

For Product A have 100 qty., For Product B i have 200 qty.

I would like to check how many products ordered for a particular product.

Which table i need to look up & what will be the query to get that in format of Magento.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get product sold quantity by product SKU for the particular product using the below-mentioned code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$soldproduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection')->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')->getFirstItem(); 
$soldnumber = $soldproduct->getOrderedQty();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 
$id = 786 // enter your product ID here
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$select = $connection->select()
    ->from(
        ['o' => 'mg_sales_order_item'],
        [ new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(o.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered') ]
    )
    ->where('o.product_id=?', $id)
    ->group('o.product_id');
```

$result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
//echo'';  print_r($result);

It's working for me