# Quantity of a product sold in the last 30 days from sku or id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to obtain the quantity that has been sold of a product from its sku or id in Magento 2. This quantity must refer to the last 30 days.

I have tried to follow what is reported here but without success:
[Magento 2: How many products sold Query](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139039/magento-2-how-many-products-sold-query)
Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution for something like this is probably using SQL and querying the database directly (if you can.) Something along the line of the following ought to work for you:

```
SELECT SUM(qty_ordered - qty_canceled - qty_refunded) as qty, product_id, sku
FROM sales_order_item
WHERE product_id IN ('<id here>','<other id here>',...)
AND updated_at >= (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY))
```

Or by sku:

```
SELECT SUM(qty_ordered - qty_canceled - qty_refunded) as qty, product_id, sku
FROM sales_order_item
WHERE sku IN ('<sku here>','<other sku here>',...)
AND updated_at >= (SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -30 DAY))
```

**Explanation:**
Order item table has the individual products added to the order. Taking the sum of ordered, then subtracting cancelled & refunded, should give an accurate count for the total actually sold. And we limit the query to the specified skus/product ids and within 30 days from the current timestamp.

It's possible there might be some edge cases that this can't pick up (obvious one is somehow cancelling an order without cancelling products / refunding them) but accounting for them makes the query a lot more complex (joins to the order table, etc.)

Comment: thanks to this help I succeeded

Comment: Glad to hear that.